# Convert a list to expected list of tuples without any iteration in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I am having a list like

```
['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

I want this list as list of tuples like

```
[('val1', False), ('val2', False), ('val3', False)]
```

This list may contains large number of data. So, I want optimized way to get expected result.

Comment: It's going to be O(n), you can't avoid iteration; just write a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: Could you edit your question to include an origin for these second values?
And @jonrsharpe is right, there is no way to do this without at least iterating once over each value, I think.

Comment: Why no iteration? It would seem that anything else would just be less efficient

Comment: There is no way to create one list from another list (and on top adding stuff to it) without going through its data. List comprehensions are iterating them as well. What did you try and what went wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension. In most cases this is the most efficient solution for constructing lists:

```
vals = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']

result = [(v, False) for v in vals]
# [('val1', False), ('val2', False), ('val3', False)]
```